# Get all the diagonals in a matrix/list of lists in Python

Tags: python, matrix, diagonal

I'm looking for a Pythonic way to get all the diagonals of a (square) matrix, represented as a list of lists.

Suppose I have the following matrix:

```
matrix = [[-2,  5,  3,  2],
          [ 9, -6,  5,  1],
          [ 3,  2,  7,  3],
          [-1,  8, -4,  8]]
```

Then the large diagonals are easy:

```
l = len(matrix[0])
print([matrix[i][i] for i in range(l)])              # [-2, -6, 7,  8]
print([matrix[l-1-i][i] for i in range(l-1,-1,-1)])  # [ 2,  5, 2, -1]
```

But I have trouble coming up with a way to generate all the diagonals. The output I'm looking for is:

```
[[-2], [9, 5], [3,-6, 3], [-1, 2, 5, 2], [8, 7, 1], [-4, 3], [8],
 [2], [3,1], [5, 5, 3], [-2, -6, 7, 8], [9, 2, -4], [3, 8], [-1]]
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

There are probably better ways to do it in [numpy](https://numpy.org/) than below, but I'm not too familiar with it yet:

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.array(
         [[-2,  5,  3,  2],
          [ 9, -6,  5,  1],
          [ 3,  2,  7,  3],
          [-1,  8, -4,  8]])

diags = [matrix[::-1,:].diagonal(i) for i in range(-3,4)]
diags.extend(matrix.diagonal(i) for i in range(3,-4,-1))
print [n.tolist() for n in diags]
```

#### Output

```
[[-2], [9, 5], [3, -6, 3], [-1, 2, 5, 2], [8, 7, 1], [-4, 3], [8], [2], [3, 1], [5, 5, 3], [-2, -6, 7, 8], [9, 2, -4], [3, 8], [-1]]
```

---

**Edit**: Updated to generalize for any matrix size.

```
import numpy as np

# Alter dimensions as needed
x,y = 3,4

# create a default array of specified dimensions
a = np.arange(x*y).reshape(x,y)
print a
print

# a.diagonal returns the top-left-to-lower-right diagonal "i"
# according to this diagram:
#
#  0  1  2  3  4 ...
# -1  0  1  2  3
# -2 -1  0  1  2
# -3 -2 -1  0  1
#  :
#
# You wanted lower-left-to-upper-right and upper-left-to-lower-right diagonals.
#
# The syntax a[slice,slice] returns a new array with elements from the sliced ranges,
# where "slice" is Python's [start[:stop[:step]] format.

# "::-1" returns the rows in reverse. ":" returns the columns as is,
# effectively vertically mirroring the original array so the wanted diagonals are
# lower-right-to-uppper-left.
#
# Then a list comprehension is used to collect all the diagonals.  The range
# is -x+1 to y (exclusive of y), so for a matrix like the example above
# (x,y) = (4,5) = -3 to 4.
diags = [a[::-1,:].diagonal(i) for i in range(-a.shape[0]+1,a.shape[1])]

# Now back to the original array to get the upper-left-to-lower-right diagonals,
# starting from the right, so the range needed for shape (x,y) was y-1 to -x+1 descending.
diags.extend(a.diagonal(i) for i in range(a.shape[1]-1,-a.shape[0],-1))

# Another list comp to convert back to Python lists from numpy arrays,
# so it prints what you requested.
print [n.tolist() for n in diags]
```

#### Output

```
[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]]

[[0], [4, 1], [8, 5, 2], [9, 6, 3], [10, 7], [11], [3], [2, 7], [1, 6, 11], [0, 5, 10], [4, 9], [8]]
```

Answer (score 46):

I came across another interesting solution to this issue.
The row, column, forward, and backward diagonal can all be immediately discovered by looking at a combination of x and y.

```
Column = x     Row = y        F-Diag = x+y   B-Diag = x-y     B-Diag` = x-y-MIN 
  | 0  1  2      | 0  1  2      | 0  1  2      | 0  1  2        | 0  1  2     
--|---------   --|---------   --|---------   --|---------     --|---------    
0 | 0  1  2    0 | 0  0  0    0 | 0  1  2    0 | 0  1  2      0 | 2  3  4     
1 | 0  1  2    1 | 1  1  1    1 | 1  2  3    1 |-1  0  1      1 | 1  2  3     
2 | 0  1  2    2 | 2  2  2    2 | 2  3  4    2 |-2 -1  0      2 | 0  1  2
```

From the diagram you can see that each diagonal and axis is uniquely identifiable using these equations. Take each unique number from each table and create a container for that identifier.

Note that the backward diagonals have been offset to start at a zero index, and that the length of forward diagonals is always equal to the length of backward diagonals.

```
test = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]

max_col = len(test[0])
max_row = len(test)
cols = [[] for _ in range(max_col)]
rows = [[] for _ in range(max_row)]
fdiag = [[] for _ in range(max_row + max_col - 1)]
bdiag = [[] for _ in range(len(fdiag))]
min_bdiag = -max_row + 1

for x in range(max_col):
    for y in range(max_row):
        cols[x].append(test[y][x])
        rows[y].append(test[y][x])
        fdiag[x+y].append(test[y][x])
        bdiag[x-y-min_bdiag].append(test[y][x])

print(cols)
print(rows)
print(fdiag)
print(bdiag)
```

Which will print

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
[[1, 4, 7, 10], [2, 5, 8, 11], [3, 6, 9, 12]]
[[1], [2, 4], [3, 5, 7], [6, 8, 10], [9, 11], [12]]
[[10], [7, 11], [4, 8, 12], [1, 5, 9], [2, 6], [3]]
```

---

Using a defaultdict and a lambda, this can be generalized further:

```
from collections import defaultdict


def groups(data, func):
    grouping = defaultdict(list)
    for y in range(len(data)):
        for x in range(len(data[y])):
            grouping[func(x, y)].append(data[y][x])
    return list(map(grouping.get, sorted(grouping)))


test = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
cols = groups(test, lambda x, y: x)
rows = groups(test, lambda x, y: y)
fdiag = groups(test, lambda x, y: x + y)
bdiag = groups(test, lambda x, y: x - y)
```

Comment: This is the best answer I've ever seen to this question.

Comment: I like this answer because it has flexibility as code and also demonstrates the mathematical relationship between the elements in the matrix and their x y coordinates.

Comment: The B-Diag` (last table) entries don't make sense. 0-0-min(0,0) = 0. How do you get 2?

Comment: @TheRealFakeNews `MIN` is a constant for minimum value seen in `B-Diag`. `0 - 0 - (-2) == 2`. This allows you to arrange the values in a list context with zero-based array indexing.

Answer (score 22):

Start with the diagonals that slope up-and-right.

If (x,y) is a rectangular coordinate inside the matrix, you want to transform to/from a coordinate scheme (p,q), where p is the number of the diagonal and q is the index along the diagonal.  (So p=0 is the [-2] diagonal, p=1 is the [9,5] diagonal, p=2 is the [3,-6,3] diagonal, and so on.)

To transform a (p,q) into an (x,y), you can use:

```
x = q
y = p - q
```

Try plugging in values of p and q to see how this is working.

Now you just loop...  For p from 0 to 2N-1, and q from max(0, p-N+1) to min(p, N-1).  Transform p,q to x,y and print.

Then for the other diagonals, repeat the loops but use a different transformation:

```
x = N - 1 - q
y = p - q
```

(This effectively just flips the matrix left-right.)

Sorry I did not actually code this in Python.  :-)

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23069625/50065) for a Python implementation.

Answer (score 19):

This is for [`Moe`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3425319/moe), who asked [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23069388/50065).

I start off by making simple functions to copy rows or columns of any rectangular matrix.

```
def get_rows(grid):
    return [[c for c in r] for r in grid]

def get_cols(grid):
    return zip(*grid)
```

With these two functions I then get the diagonals by adding an increasing/decreasing buffer to the start/end of each row. I then get the columns of this buffered grid, then remove the buffer on each column afterwards. ie)

```
1 2 3    |X|X|1|2|3|    | | |1|2|3|
4 5 6 => |X|4|5|6|X| => | |4|5|6| | => [[7],[4,8],[1,5,9],[2,6],[3]]
7 8 9    |7|8|9|X|X|    |7|8|9| | |
```

.

```
def get_backward_diagonals(grid):
    b = [None] * (len(grid) - 1)
    grid = [b[i:] + r + b[:i] for i, r in enumerate(get_rows(grid))]
    return [[c for c in r if c is not None] for r in get_cols(grid)]

def get_forward_diagonals(grid):
    b = [None] * (len(grid) - 1)
    grid = [b[:i] + r + b[i:] for i, r in enumerate(get_rows(grid))]
    return [[c for c in r if c is not None] for r in get_cols(grid)]
```

Answer (score 8):

I ended up reinventing this wheel recently. Here's an easy-to-reuse/extend method to find the diagonals in a square list-of-lists:

```
def get_diagonals(grid, bltr = True):
  dim = len(grid)
  assert dim == len(grid[0])
  return_grid = [[] for total in xrange(2 * len(grid) - 1)]
  for row in xrange(len(grid)):
    for col in xrange(len(grid[row])):
      if bltr: return_grid[row + col].append(grid[col][row])
      else:    return_grid[col - row + (dim - 1)].append(grid[row][col])
  return return_grid
```

Assuming list indices:

> 00 01 02 03
>
> 10 11 12 13
>
> 20 21 22 23
>
> 30 31 32 33

then setting `bltr = True` (the default), returns the diagonals from bottom-left to top-right, i.e.

```
00           # row + col == 0
10 01        # row + col == 1
20 11 02     # row + col == 2
30 21 12 03  # row + col == 3
31 22 13     # row + col == 4
32 23        # row + col == 5
33           # row + col == 6
```

setting `bltr = False`, returns the diagonals from bottom-left to top-right, i.e.

```
30            # (col - row) == -3
20 31         # (col - row) == -2
10 21 32      # (col - row) == -1
00 11 22 33   # (col - row) == 0
01 12 23      # (col - row) == +1
02 13         # (col - row) == +2
03            # (col - row) == +3
```

[Here's a runnable version](https://repl.it/JuZ3) using OP's input matrix.

Answer (score 2):

I guess there's an easier way to do this now. (But only use this if you are already familiar with the above answers).

```
from collections import defaultdict
```

There's this method called *defaultdict* which is imported from the *collections* module, is used to create dictionaries if you don't know the key you are going to have.

We use this in these situations:

- If you don't know the key but want to assign some value to a particular key.
- Normal dictionary raises keyerror if the key is not present in the dictionary. But this won't ( you can assign some function to it if you want)

After Importing, you can run the following code and check.

```
rows,cols = 3,3
matrix = [[1, 2, 3],
          [4, 5, 6],
          [7, 8, 9]]

diagonal1 = defaultdict(list) # For the top right to bottom left
diagonal2 = defaultdict(list) # For the top left to bottom right
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        diagonal1[i-j].append(matrix[i][j])
        diagonal2[i+j].append(matrix[i][j])
print(diagonal1,'\n',diagonal2)
```

> The *list* parameter will create a list of values for that particular key.

The output is as follows:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {0: [1, 5, 9], -1: [2, 6], -2: [3], 1: [4, 8], 2: [7]}) 
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {0: [1], 1: [2, 4], 2: [3, 5, 7], 3: [6, 8], 4: [9]})
```

Now you can use both the diagonals as you want.

To know more about defaultdict use this link :
[Click here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/defaultdict-in-python/)

Answer (score 1):

**This only works for matricies of equal width and height.**
But it also doesn't rely on any third parties.

```
matrix = [[11, 2, 4],[4, 5, 6],[10, 8, -12]]

# only works for diagnoals of equal width and height
def forward_diagonal(matrix):
    if not isinstance(matrix, list):
        raise TypeError("Must be of type list")

    results = []
    x = 0
    for k, row in enumerate(matrix):
        # next diag is (x + 1, y + 1)
        for i, elm in enumerate(row):

            if i == 0 and k == 0:
                results.append(elm)
                break
            if (x + 1 == i):
                results.append(elm)
                x = i
                break
    return results

print 'forward diagnoals', forward_diagonal(matrix)
```

Answer (score 1):

Code based on Nemo's answer above:

```
def print_diagonals(matrix):
    n = len(matrix)
    diagonals_1 = []  # lower-left-to-upper-right diagonals
    diagonals_2 = []  # upper-left-to-lower-right diagonals
    for p in range(2*n-1):
        diagonals_1.append([matrix[p-q][q] for q in range(max(0, p - n + 1), min(p, n - 1) + 1)])
        diagonals_2.append([matrix[n-p+q-1][q] for q in range(max(0, p - n + 1), min(p, n - 1) + 1)])
    print("lower-left-to-upper-right diagonals: ", diagonals_1)
    print("upper-left-to-lower-right diagonals: ", diagonals_2)


print_diagonals([
    [1, 2, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 4, 1],
    [1, 3, 1, 6],
    [1, 7, 2, 5],
])

lower-left-to-upper-right diagonals:  [[1], [1, 2], [1, 1, 1], [1, 3, 4, 1], [7, 1, 1], [2, 6], [5]]
upper-left-to-lower-right diagonals:  [[1], [1, 7], [1, 3, 2], [1, 1, 1, 5], [2, 4, 6], [1, 1], [1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Pythonic approach**

For a pure Python implementation I would suggest to work in 1D.

```
W, H = len(mat[0]), len(mat) 
idx = range(W-1) + range(W-1, W*H, W)
rng = range(1, W) + range(H, 0, -1)
rng = map(lambda x: x if (x < min(W, H)) else min(W, H), rng)
dia = [[i + (W-1) * m for m in xrange(r)] for i, r in zip(idx, rng)]
```

Here `dia` returns a list of indices for each diagonal. To retrieve the corresponding values:

```
arr = [e for row in mat for e in row] #Flatten the matrix
for d in dia:
    print [arr[e] for e in d][::-1]

[-2]
[9, 5]
[3, -6, 3]
[-1, 2, 5, 2]
[8, 7, 1]
[-4, 3]
[8]
```

If you want to return the values in the opposite direction:

```
arr2 = [e for row in zip(*mat[::-1]) for e in row] #Flatten and rotate the matrix by 90°
for d in dia[::-1]:
    print [arr2[e] for e in d]

[2]
[3, 1]
[5, 5, 3]
[-2, -6, 7, 8]
[9, 2, -4]
[3, 8]
[-1]
```

**Numpy approach**

```
tril = [np.flip(np.fliplr(mat).diagonal(n)) for n in xrange(mat.shape[0])][::-1]
trir = [np.flipud(mat).diagonal(n) for n in xrange(1, mat.shape[0])]
dia = tril + trir

[array([-2]),
 array([9, 5]),
 array([ 3, -6,  3]),
 array([-1,  2,  5,  2]),
 array([8, 7, 1]),
 array([-4,  3]),
 array([8])]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
import numpy as np
matrix = [[-2,  5,  3,  2],
          [ 9, -6,  5,  1],
          [ 3,  2,  7,  3],
          [-1,  8, -4,  8]]

matrix = np.array(matrix)
matrix = np.flipud(matrix)
a = matrix.shape[0]
list_ = [np.diag(matrix, k=i).tolist() for i in range(-a+1,a)]
print(list_)
```

**Output** :

```
[[-2], [9, 5], [3, -6, 3], [-1, 2, 5, 2], [8, 7, 1], [-4, 3], [8]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using dict

```
mat = [[-2,  5,  3,  2],
      [ 9, -6,  5,  1],
      [ 3,  2,  7,  3],
      [-1,  8, -4,  8]]
dct = dict()
for i in range(len(mat)-1,-len(mat[0]),-1):
    dct[i] = []
for i in range(len(mat)):
    for j in range(len(mat[0])):
       dct[i-j].append(mat[i][j])
print(dct)
```

Output:

```
{3: [-1], 2: [3, 8], 1: [9, 2, -4], 0: [-2, -6, 7, 8], -1: [5, 5, 3], -2: [3, 1], -3: [2]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using itertools

```
matrix = [[-2,  5,  3,  2],
      [ 9, -6,  5,  1],
      [ 3,  2,  7,  3],
      [-1,  8, -4,  8]]

import itertools as it

def show_diagonals(alist):

    # get row/col lenght
    a = len(alist)

    # creating a fliped matrix
    rlist = []
    for r in alist:
        new = r.copy()
        new.reverse()
        rlist.append(new)

    flatten_list = list(it.chain.from_iterable(alist)) 
    flatten_rlist = list(it.chain.from_iterable(rlist)) 
    b = len(flatten_list)
    first_diag = list(it.islice(flatten_list, 0, b+1, a+1))
    second_diag = list(it.islice(flatten_rlist, 0, b+1, a+1))
    return first_diag, second_diag

a, b = show_diagonals(matrix)
```

Answer (score 1):

***Itertools to the rescue!*** with some nice one-liners...

*For a `dim`x`dim` square matrix,*

```py
itertools.groupby(
   sorted(itertools.product(range(dim), repeat=2), key=sum),
   key=sum,
)
```

*In the arbitrary `nrow`x`ncol`case,*

```py
itertools.groupby(
   sorted(itertools.product(range(nrow), range(ncol)), key=sum),
   key=sum,
)
```

***How does this work?*** We want to see all combinations of row and column indices --- this is a product. Sort by `(row, col)` coordinate sums to get ascending diagonals (i.e., `(0, 0)` has sum `0` and will be ordered first). The stability of `sort` and the iteration order of `product` gets us the sequential ordering along same-sum diagonals. Finally, `groupby` clumps our diagonals together.

***Examples***

With `dim = 3`,

```py
>>> import itertools as it
>>> for diagonal, coords in it.groupby(
...     sorted(it.product(range(3), repeat=2), key=sum),
...     key=sum,
...):
...     print(f"{diagonal=}")
...     print("coords=", [*coords], "\n")
... 
diagonal=0
coords= [(0, 0)] 

diagonal=1
coords= [(0, 1), (1, 0)] 

diagonal=2
coords= [(0, 2), (1, 1), (2, 0)] 

diagonal=3
coords= [(1, 2), (2, 1)] 

diagonal=4
coords= [(2, 2)]
```

With `nrow=3` and `ncol=2`,

```py
>>> for diagonal, coords in it.groupby(
...     sorted(it.product(range(3), range(2)), key=sum), 
...     key=sum,
...):
...     print(f"{diagonal=}")
...     print("coords=", [*coords], "\n")
... 
diagonal=0
coords= [(0, 0)] 

diagonal=1
coords= [(0, 1), (1, 0)] 

diagonal=2
coords= [(1, 1), (2, 0)] 

diagonal=3
coords= [(2, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using some numpy-fu to get the main diagonal:**

```
import numpy as np  
r = np.arange(36) 
r.resize((6, 6)) 
print(r) 
r = r.reshape(len(r)**2)[::len(r)+1] 
print(r)
```

Prints:

```
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8  9 10 11]
 [12 13 14 15 16 17]
 [18 19 20 21 22 23]
 [24 25 26 27 28 29]
 [30 31 32 33 34 35]]

[ 0  7 14 21 28 35]
```

Comment: You should add some explanation, visualisation or raw output to make your answer more clear.

Answer (score -1):

From here : [np.Diagonal](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html)

```
 np.diagonal(matrix)
```

Comment: This will only return the large diagonal `array([-2, -6,  7,  8])`, not all the other diagonals.