# checking diagonals in 2d list (Python)

Tags: python, 2d

The initial problem: for a given 3x3 tic tac toe board check if one of the players has won.

The simplest solution I have come up so far is rotating the matrix and summing up each row:

```
board
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]

pr(board)
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8

pr(zip(*board))
0 3 6
1 4 7
2 5 8
```

0..9 numbers above are just for showing positions on the board, normally they would be filled with 1 for player 1 and -1 for player 2 and 0 for unfilled position. Go row by row and if it sums up to 3 or -3 this is the winning block.

However, diagonals are not checked. Is there some way to extract diagonals from such matrix in elegant + highly performant way? I don't mean using trivial indexes "manually" (0, 1, 2), but rather get diagonal of n x n matrix.

P.S. pr is just a helper function for printing 2d list:

```
def pr(x):
    for row in x:
        print ' '.join(map(str, row))
```

Comment: What is the `pr` function?

Comment: helper function, see P.S. after my edit now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Number your game field with a magic square

```
2|9|4
7|5|3
6|1|8
```

Now sum up after three moves and check if the sum is 15 --> Winner. You have to check this for every player. Surely you have to recheck after 4th move and 5th move (only the player that started the game)

This is how I solved this problem in my first Java class.

Comment: although not the direct answer, this is the most creative solution

Answer (score 12):

You can get one diagonal with:

```
[r[i] for i, r in enumerate(board)]
# [0, 4, 8]
```

And the opposite diagonal with:

```
[r[-i-1] for i, r in enumerate(board)]
# [2, 4, 6]
```

Comment: You can make `-i-1` into `~i`

Comment: elegant solution!

Comment: for the opposite one, it can be done also in this way: `[r[i] for i, r in enumerate(board[::-1])]`

Answer (score 2):

Probably what you need is in `numpy`, see [Get all the diagonals in a matrix/list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313308/get-all-the-diagonals-in-a-matrix-list-of-lists-in-python). Maybe you can use this, and flip it like you did to get the other solution.

```
if sum(board[i][i] for i in (0, 1, 2)) in (-3, 3):
    true
```

Answer (score 2):

The diagonals on a square board lie either where the indices are equal, so for a 3x3 board they are
`board[0][0]`, `board[1][1]`, and `board[2][2]` or where the two sum to the board size-1 (3 places in this case): such as `board[0][2]`, `board[1][1]`, and `board[2][0]` -- notice that `board[1][1]` is included in both sets, as it should be. These facts makes it fairly easy to write Python code to compute them:

```
board = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
BOARD_SIZE = len(board)

diags1 = [board[i][i] for i in xrange(BOARD_SIZE)]
diags2 = [board[i][BOARD_SIZE-1-i] for i in xrange(BOARD_SIZE)]

print diags1
print diags2
```

Output:

```
[0, 4, 8]
[2, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a list containing the diagonal elements of one direction (top left to bottom right):

```
[board[i][i] for i in range(len(board))]
```

This will do the same for the opposite direction:

```
[board[i][len(board)-i-1] for i in range(len(board))]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
tmp_diagonals = [set(), set()]
    num = 0
    for idx in range(len(board) - 1, -1, -1):
        tmp_diagonals[0].add(board[num][num])
        tmp_diagonals[1].add(board[num][idx])
        num += 1
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of your code?

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including a detailed explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.