# Diagonal of a nested list in Python 3

Tags: python, list, nested

I have a several lists within a list which forms a game of noughts and crosses:

```
list = [
        ['X', 'O', 'O'], 
        ['O', 'X', 'O'], 
        [' ', 'X', ' ']
       ]
```

I need to write a function that returns the diagonals of the game from top left to bottom right and then top right to bottom left so the output would be:

```
diags = (['X', 'X', ' '],['O', 'X', ' '])
```

I have tried various combinations of nested for loops, can't seem to get my head around it though.

Comment: See this answer, which I think covers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15100815/399704

Comment: possible duplicate of [checking diagonals in 2d list (Python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100735/checking-diagonals-in-2d-list-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
nw_to_se = [your_list[i][i] for i in range(3)]
ne_to_sw = [your_list[i][2-i] for i in range(3)]
diags = (nw_to_se, ne_to_sw)
```

Instead of `[2-i]` you could also use `[-i-1]`, which scales to any size square.

Comment: I had to change ne_to_sw = [your_list[2-i][i] for i in range(3)] to ne_to_sw = [your_list[i][2-i] for i in range(3)] for it to be in the correct order. Thank you very much though!