# Print 2d array on diagonals

Tags: python, matrix

I'm trying to print the diagonals for a 2d array starting with the bottom left corner and moving towards the top right corner. I've managed to print the first half of the matrix but I got stuck when I have to print the second part of it and I'm hoping somebody can give me a clue how to continue. Here is what I have:

```
matrix = [["A", "B", "C", "D"], 
          ["E", "F", "G", "H"], 
          ["I", "J", "K", "L"],
          ["M", "N", "O", "P"],
          ["Q", "R", "S", "T"]]
```

and the partial function that print the diagonals up to a point:

```
def diagonal_matrix_print(input_matrix):
    width = len(input_matrix[0])
    height = len(input_matrix)
    start_row = height - 1
    first_row = 0 
    for start_row in reversed(range(0, height)):
        i = start_row
        for column in range(0, width):
            if i == height:
                start_row = start_row - 1
                break
            print input_matrix[i][column]
            i = i + 1
        print
```

The issue I'm facing is printing the diagonals that start with the second half of the matrix - `B G L, C H, D`

I tried using another 2 for loops for it like:

```
for row in range (0, height -1):
    i = row
    for start_column in range(1, width):
        print input_matrix[i][start_column]
        i = i + 1
```

but when the row value changes to 1, is not printing the diagonal anymore...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6313308/190597

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have the list of lists `L`:

```
>>> L = [[ 0,  1,  2],
         [ 3,  4,  5],
         [ 6,  7,  8],
         [ 9, 10, 11]])
```

We want a function `diagonals` such that

```
>>> diagonals(L)
[[9], [6, 10], [3, 7, 11], [0, 4, 8], [1, 5], [2]]
```

We can think about items in `L` with respect to 2 different coordinate
systems. There is the usual `(x, y)` coordinate system where `(x, y)` corresponds to
the location with value `L[x][y]`.

And then there is also the `(p, q)` coordinate system where `p` represents the
`pth` diagonal, with `p=0` being the diag at the *lower-left corner*.  And `q`
represents the `qth` item along the `pth` diag, with `q=0` starting at the *left
edge*. Thus `(p, q) = (0,0)` corresponds to the location with value `L[3][0] = 9`
in the example above.

Let `h,w` equal the height and width of `L` respectively.
Then `p` ranges from `0` to `h + w - 1`.

We want a formula for translating from `(p, q)` coordinates to `(x, y)` coordinates.

- `x` decreases linearly as `p` increases.
- `x` increases linearly as `q` increases.
- When `(p, q) = (0, 0)`, `x` equals `h`.

Therefore: `x = h - p + q`.

- `y` does not change with `p` (if `q` is fixed).
- `y` increases linearly as `q` increases.
- When `(p, q) = (0, 0)`, `y` equals `q`.

Therefore, `y = q`.

Now the extent of valid values for `x` and `y` requires that:

```
(0 <= x = h - p + q < h) and (0 <= y = q < w)
```

which is equivalent to

```
(p - h + 1 <= q < p + 1) and (0 <= q < w)
```

which is equivalent to

```
max(p - h + 1, 0) <= q < min(p + 1, w)
```

Therefore we can loop through the items of `L` using

```
for p in range(h + w - 1):
    for q in range(max(p-h+1, 0), min(p+1, w))
        L[h - p + q - 1][q]
```

---

```
def diagonals(L):
    h, w = len(L), len(L[0])
    return [[L[h - p + q - 1][q]
             for q in range(max(p-h+1, 0), min(p+1, w))]
            for p in range(h + w - 1) ]


matrix = [ ["A", "B", "C", "D"], ["E","F","G","H"], ["I","J","K","L"], ["M","N","O","P"], ["Q", "R", "S","T"]]

for diag in diagonals(matrix):
    print(diag)
```

yields

```
['Q']
['M', 'R']
['I', 'N', 'S']
['E', 'J', 'O', 'T']
['A', 'F', 'K', 'P']
['B', 'G', 'L']
['C', 'H']
['D']
```

Comment: very logical solution , thank you. Taking the code I wrote, isn't a way of doing this by just using 2 for loops to print the other half of the matrix?