# Sum of diagonal elements in a matrix

Tags: python, matrix

I am trying to find out the sum of the diagonal elements in a matrix. Here, n is the size of the square matrix and a is the matrix. Can someone explain this to me what is happening here.

```
n = 3
a = [[11,2,4],[4,5,6],[10,8,-12]]
sum_first_diagonal = sum(a[i][i] for i in range(n))
sum_second_diagonal = sum(a[n-i-1][n-i-1] for i in range(n))
print(str(sum_first_diagonal)+" "+str(sum_first_diagonal))
```

Comment: You are summing the same diagonal twice, once from top left to bottom right and then the other way around.  I don't believe that this code snippet can print anything other than `4 4` on any Python installation.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this for summing your second diagonal:

```
sum(a[i][n-i-1] for i in range(n))
```

The inner loop accesses these entries:

```
>>> n = 3
>>> [(i, n-i-1) for i in range(n)]
[(0, 2), (1, 1), (2, 0)]
```

And the summed value of this diagonal for your sample matrix is:

```
>>> n = 3
>>> sum(a[i][n-i-1] for i in range(n))
19
```

The mistake in your code is to use the same expression for both dimensions:

```
a[n-i-1][n-i-1]
```

which will process the first diagonal again in reverse order `[(2, 2), (1, 1), (0, 0)]` giving you the same sum twice.

Answer (score 25):

Use numpy library which is powerful for any matrix calculations. For your specific case:

```
import numpy as np
a = [[11,2,4],[4,5,6],[10,8,-12]]
b = np.asarray(a)
print('Diagonal (sum): ', np.trace(b))
print('Diagonal (elements): ', np.diagonal(b))
```

You can easily install numpy with pip or other ways that you will find on many webs.

If you want all the diagonals, and not just the main diagonal, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313308/get-all-the-diagonals-in-a-matrix-list-of-lists-in-python) that also uses numpy.

**EDIT**

mhawke, if you want to calculate antidiagonal (secondary diagonal), as explained in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_diagonal), you can flip the matrix in numpy

```
import numpy as np
a = [[11,2,4],[4,5,6],[10,8,-12]]
b = np.asarray(a)
b = np.fliplr(b)
print('Antidiagonal (sum): ', np.trace(b))
print('Antidiagonal (elements): ', np.diagonal(b))
```

Comment: I think the OP is unable to use `numpy` since they are submitting their code to an online judge that does not permit `numpy`. How is the second diagonal calculated?

Answer (score 1):

getting total and diagonal sum from a squared matrix

```
squared_matrix = [[2,3,4],[4,3,3],[3,3,4]]
s, ds = get_sum(squared_matrix)

def get_sum(diag_mat):
    n = len(diag_mat)
    total = sum([diag_mat[i][j] for i in range(n) for j in range(j)]
    d_sum = sum([diag_mat[i][j] if i==j else 0 for i in range(n) for j in range(j)]
   return d_sum, total
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler way to get the full `primary diagonal` and `secondary diagonal`

```
squared_matrix = [
    [2, 3, 4],
    [4, 3, 3],
    [3, 3, 4]
]


def primary_diagonal(matrix):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        sum += matrix[i][i]
    return sum

def secondary_left_diagonal(matrix):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        sum += matrix[i][len(matrix) - i - 1]
    return sum


print(primary_diagonal(squared_matrix))
print(secondary_left_diagonal(squared_matrix))
```

**Result**

```
9
10
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
n=3
sum_second_diagonal=sum([a[i][j] for i in range(n) for j in range(n) if i==j]) #it will add when i==j
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum_up_diagonals(li):
index = len(li)
first_dia =  sum(li[i][i]for i in range(index))
second_dia = sum(li[i][index-i-1]for i in range(index))
return (first_dia,second_dia)
```

Pass in your list.
This should work for you :)

Answer (score 0):

O(n) time solution to find the diagonal difference of given multidimensional array.

```
def diagonalDifference(arr):
        # arr[0][0], arr[1][1], arr[2][2]
        # arr[0][2], arr[1][1], arr[2][0]
        sumOfDiagonalFromLeft = 0
        sumOfDiagonalFromRight = 0
        pointIndexFromLeft = 0
        pointIndexFromLast = len(arr)-1
        for i in range(len(arr)):
            sumOfDiagonalFromLeft += arr[i][pointIndexFromLeft]
            # print(arr[i][pointIndexFromLeft])
            pointIndexFromLeft += 1
        
        for i in range(len(arr)):
            sumOfDiagonalFromRight += arr[i][pointIndexFromLast]
            # print(arr[i][pointIndexFromLast])
            if pointIndexFromLast < 0:
                break
            else:
                pointIndexFromLast -= 1
    
        diagonalDifference = abs(sumOfDiagonalFromLeft - sumOfDiagonalFromRight)
        return diagonalDifference
    
arr = [[11, 2, 4], [4, 5, 6], [10, 8, -12]]
print(diagonalDifference(arr))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//we simply swap  corner elements of matrix

def diagonalDifference(arr):

    c=0;d=0
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        for j in range(len(arr)):
            if i==j :
                c = c+ arr[i][j]
        for k in range(len(arr)):
            arr[i][k-1],arr[i][k-2] = arr[i][k-2],arr[i][k-1]
        

        for j in range(len(arr)):
            if i==j :
                d = d + arr[i][j]
        for k in range(len(arr)):
            arr[i][k-1],arr[i][k-2] = arr[i][k-2],arr[i][k-1]
            
    
    
    print(c,d)  
    result = abs(c-d)
    print(result)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer]. This is particularly important when answering old questions (this one is 5.5 years old) with existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

**Python 3 Solution with dynamic inputs of matrix as list inputs**

```
#Even matrix size is dynamic in this code as "n".

n=int(input())
s1=0
s2=0
a =[]
for i in range(n):

    # x here take input of size n and as separate lists to act like a matrix.

    x=list(map(int,input().strip().split()))[:n]
    a.append(x)
for i in range(n):
    s1+=a[i][i]
    s2+=a[i][n-i-1]

# If use abs() only if non-negative output is needed!!
print(abs(s1-s2)) 
# First enter the size of matrix then enter the matrix vales with spaces in each line
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a square matrix (nxn), you can compute the sums of both primary and secondary diagonals with only 1 iteration through the rows of the matrix; by keeping track of the indices involved in each computation.

```
mat = [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [9,8,9]
]

primary = 0
secondary = 0
low = 0 # start index for primary
high = len(mat)-1 # end index for secondary

for row in mat:
    primary += row[low]
    secondary += row[high]
    low += 1
    high -= 1

print(f'Primary Sum = {primary}', f'Secondary Sum = {secondary}', sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose, you have a matrix A n×m.

```
  A = [[random.rand() for i in range(n+1)] for i in range(m+1)]
  
  d = m+n-1 # that's the overall number of different diagonals
  sumrow = [0]*d # I'd like to create a list of all the sums of those
  for diag in range(d): # iterate by diagonal number
      # A difference of two related spike functions, so that it was a spike without the top
      diaglength = int(max(0,1+d/2-abs(diag+1/2-d/2)) - max(0,1+d/2-n-abs(diag+1/2-d/2)))
      # initial coordinates for further iteration inside sum() function
      x = max(0, diag-m+1)
      y = max(0, m-diag-1)
      # iterating values along the current diagonal
      sumrow[diag]=sum(A[x+i][y+i] for i in range(0,diaglength))
```

Thus, sumrow[] is a list of every sum of every diagonal, choose and don't get puddled up. I think, it's obvious what to cut off this code to get some specific value immediately.
Technically, this code could be compressed in one line. Really long line.

But why?

Answer (score 0):

mat =  [[1 ,2, 3, 4,5],[1,2,1,2,3],[2,3,4,5,2],[1,3,5,1,1],[1,2,1,2,1]]

def isSquare(mat):
if len(mat) == 1:
return True
for i in range(len(mat)):
if len(mat[i]) != len(mat):
print("Matrix is not Squared")
return False
return True

def sumOfLeftDiagonal(mat):
d1 = 0
size = len(mat)
for i in range(0,size):
for j in range(0,size):
if i == j:
d1 = d1 + mat[i][j]
return d1

def sumOfRightDiagonal(mat):
d2 = 0
size = len(mat)
for i in range(0,size):
d2 = d2 + mat[i][(size-1)-i]
return d2

if isSquare(mat):
if len(mat) == 1:
print("Difference: ",mat[0])
else:
print("sumOfLeftDiagonal: ",sumOfLeftDiagonal(mat))
print("sumOfRightDiagonal: ",sumOfRightDiagonal(mat))
print("Difference: ",abs(sumOfLeftDiagonal(mat)-sumOfRightDiagonal(mat)))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way one how to do it:

Since the matrix is square we can get sum of a diagonal and anti-diagonal by using a original and reversed lists.

```
matrix = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]

to_sum =[]                             # an empty list for collection values

for i in range(len(matrix)):           # diagonal coordinats [0][0], [1][1].... [n][n]
    to_sum.append(matrix[i][i])        # append value of diagonal
    rev = matrix[i][::-1]              # for anti-diagonal reverse list
    to_sum.append(rev[i])              # append value of anti-diagonal
                                       # to_sum list [1, 4, 6, 7, 11, 10, 16, 13]
return sum(to_sum)                     # return sum of all values in list (68)
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you know the positions of the diagonal elements for row `i`, you can write it quite densely like:

```
d = sum(row[i] + row[-1-i] for i, row in a)
```

And, for odd sized matrices, you shouldn't add the center element twice:

```
if len(a)%2:
    centre = len(a)//2
    d -= a[centre][centre]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def sum_diagnol():
    import random
    sum=0
    r1=int(input("row"))
    c1=int(input("col"))
    a=[[random.random()for col in range(c1)]for row in range(r1)]
    print("enter elements")
    for i in range(r1):
        for j in range(c1):
            a[i][j]=int(input("enter elements"))
    r2=int(input("row"))
    c2=int(input("col"))
    b=[[random.random()for col in range(c2)]for row in range(r2)]
    print("enter elements")
    for i in range(r2):
        for j in range(c2):
            b[i][j]=int(input("enter elements"))
    c=[[random.random()for col in range(c2)]for row in range(r1)]
    if(c1==r2):
        for i in range(r1):
            for j in range(c2):
                c[i][j]=0
                for k in range(c2):
                    c[i][j]=a[j][k]*b[k][j]
    else:
        print("multiplication not possible")
    for i in range(r1):
        for j in range(c2):
            print(c[i][j],end=" ")
        print()
sum_diagnol()
```

Comment: Please explain how this is an answer to the question

Answer (score -1):

I found a simple algorithm to accomplish this task.

> 1. Store the square matrix in a single one dimensional array.
> 2. Let 'n' be the order of square matrix.
> 3. There are two diagonals , one that starts from the leftmost element in top row and 
>      another that starts from nth element of the top row.
> 4. To get the indexes of numbers on the diagonal that starts from left most element in top row ,from the array containing all the numbers in the matrix; just add (n+1) recursively starting from index 1.
>      That is, indexes of elements in left to right diagonal in the array are, 1, 1+(n+1) , (n+2)+(n+1) , (2n+3)+(n+1) till the last index of array.
> 5. To get the indexes of another diagonal's numbers from the array containing all the numbers in the matrix ; just add (n-1) recursively to the indexes starting from index equals to the 'n', which is the order of the square matrix.
>      That is, indexes of elements in right to left diagonal in the array are, n, n+(n-1), (2n-1)+(n-1) and so on till the index equals to 'length of the array - (n-1)'.
> 6. If the order is odd then subtract the middle number in the array from the final sum.
>
> The example 'c++' code is as follows:

```
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;

int sumOfDiagonalNumbersInSquareMatrix(int numberArray[],int order){
int sumOfLeftToRightDiagonal = 0;
int sumOfRightToLeftDiagonal = 0;
int length = order*order;
for(int i=0; i<length;i+=(order+1)){
    //cout<<numberArray[i]<<"\t";
    sumOfLeftToRightDiagonal = sumOfLeftToRightDiagonal + numberArray[i];

}
for(int i=(order-1);i<=length-order;i+=(order-1)){
    //cout<<numberArray[i]<<"\t";
    sumOfRightToLeftDiagonal = sumOfRightToLeftDiagonal + numberArray[i];
}
if(order % 2 != 0){
    return (sumOfLeftToRightDiagonal + sumOfRightToLeftDiagonal) - numberArray[(length/2)];
}
return (sumOfLeftToRightDiagonal + sumOfRightToLeftDiagonal);
}

 int main(){
 int nums[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16};
 cout<<sumOfDiagonalNumbersInSquareMatrix(nums,4);
 return 0;
 }
```

> You can run it here: http://cpp.sh/6cmdp

Answer (score -1):

***I don't understand why no one posted any good solution.
Here is as descent solution:***

```
length = len(arr)
r1 = 0
r2 = 0
for i in range(length):
    r1 += arr[i][length - i - 1]
    r2 += arr[i][i]
print(r1 + r2)
# If you want sum of there absolute values
print(abs(r1) + abs(r2))
```

***Here arr is a 2d list.***

Answer (score -1):

'''

```
a = [[],[],[]] #your matrix
s = 0
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a[0])):
           if i == j:
               s += a[i][j]
print('sum ='s)
```

'''
here is a simple approach.
Thanks