# to print all the diagonal elements for a given array

Tags: python, matrix, diagonal

```
a = [['a','b','c'],
    ['d','e','f','g'],
    ['h','i','j','k'],
    ['l','m','n']]
```

I need to print the diagonal elements of the given array such as output would be:

```
[['l'],['h','m'],['d','i','n'],['a','e','j'],['b','f','k'],['c','g']]
```

Comment: i m try to do that in python 2.6, fyi

Comment: Okay, go on, keep us posted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all the diagonals in a matrix/list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313308/get-all-the-diagonals-in-a-matrix-list-of-lists-in-python)

Comment: @APorter1031 Not sure if numpy would work with strings.

Comment: numpy is not working for strings :(

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please [edit] your question to include your attempt and any specific question regarding it. See [ask] for more information.

Comment: @TemporalWolf : is my question not clear enough ?

Comment: What you need to do is try to solve it yourself. [so] is not a code writing service.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: `numpy` would work if your list was not "staggered". strings have nothing to do with it.

Comment: @TemporalWolf : i appreciate the sentiment, and i did try to write it myself too...but was stuck after two lines.
and stackoverflow is not a coding service and as a learner i am in debt of it,

Comment: @MooingRawr:point taken, thank you for the feedback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it's more or less like this:

```
    a = [
    ['a','b','c'],
    ['d','e','f','g'],
    ['h','i','j','k'],
    ['l','m','n']
    ]

d = 0
while True:
  array = []
  j = (len(a)-1)-d
  k = 0
  if j<0:
    k= -j
    j = 0
  while j<len(a) and k<len(a[j]):
    array.append(a[j][k])    
    j+=1
    k+=1
  if len(array) == 0:
    break

  print(array)
  d+=1
```