# How to get the diagonals of all rows in a 2D numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given this numpy array

```
[[200.       202.08165 ]
 [189.60295  190.32434 ]
 [189.19751  188.7867  ]
 [162.15639  164.05934 ]]
```

I want to get this array

```
[[200.       190.32434 ]
 [189.60295  188.7867  ]
 [189.19751  164.05934 ]]
```

The same for 3 columns, given this array

```
[[200.       202.08165    187.8392 ]
 [189.60295  190.32434    167.93082]
 [189.19751  188.7867     199.2839 ]
 [162.15639  164.05934    200.92   ]]
```

I want to get this array

```
[[200.       190.32434    199.2839 ]
 [189.60295  188.7867     200.92   ]]
```

Any vectorized way to achieve this for any number of columns and rows? `np.diag` and `np.diagonal` only seem to give me a single diagonal, but I need all of them stacked up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all the diagonals in a matrix/list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313308/get-all-the-diagonals-in-a-matrix-list-of-lists-in-python)

Comment: @b-fg Unfortunately not, there's no vectorized method among those answers and also my case is different. I think it should be clear from the examples I've given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems like a specialized case of keeping diagonal elements. Here's one vectorized solution using `masking` -

```
def keep_diag(a):    
    m,n = a.shape
    i,j = np.ogrid[:m,:n]
    mask = (i>=j) & ((i-m+n)<=j)
    return a.T[mask.T].reshape(n,-1).T
```

Most of the trick is at the step of `mask` creation, which when masked with the input array gets us the required elements off it.

Sample runs -

```
In [105]: a
Out[105]: 
array([[ 0, 16],
       [11, 98],
       [81, 63],
       [83, 20]])

In [106]: keep_diag(a)
Out[106]: 
array([[ 0, 98],
       [11, 63],
       [81, 20]])

In [102]: a
Out[102]: 
array([[10,  2, 66],
       [44, 18, 35],
       [70,  8, 31],
       [12, 27, 86]])

In [103]: keep_diag(a)
Out[103]: 
array([[10, 18, 31],
       [44,  8, 86]])
```

Answer (score 1):

you can still use `np.diagonal()`:

```
import numpy as np
b= np.array([[200.     , 202.08165, 187.8392 ],
             [189.60295, 190.32434, 167.93082],
             [189.19751, 188.7867 , 199.2839 ],
             [162.15639, 164.05934, 200.92   ]])  

diags = np.asarray([b[i:,:].diagonal() for i in range(b.shape[0]-b.shape[1]+1)])
```