# Input numbers on diagonals of matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I need to work with a matrix. You should be able to input numbers in matrix (for example if i need to have 1 on the diagonal and 0.6 up and under the diagonal i can just input it, 0.6 is only on the line under the diagonal). It has a simple solution but gets tricky when i also want to edit size of the matrix.

Im using numpy library

Comment: Can you please provide some example of what you've already done, also what the input and output should look like.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a matrix like this:

```
[1. , 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6]
[0.6, 1. , 0.6, 0.6, 0.6]
[0.6, 0.6, 1. , 0.6, 0.6]
[0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 1. , 0.6]
[0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 1. ]
```

```
import numpy as np

# First, you create a matrix full of the numbers outside the diagonal (let's use 5 as an example of the matrix' shape)

matrix = np.full((5,5),0.6)

# Then, you can edit the diagonal but using "numpy.diag_indices_from":

matrix[np.diag_indices_from(matrix)] = 1

print(matrix)
```

Out:

```
array([[1. , 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6],
       [0.6, 1. , 0.6, 0.6, 0.6],
       [0.6, 0.6, 1. , 0.6, 0.6],
       [0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 1. , 0.6],
       [0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 1. ]])
```

Comment: thanks, but is there some way to acces numbers under the diagonal ? i dont meen all the numberes there just the line under the diagonal

Comment: @Jatel by "the line under the diagonal" you mean the 'other diagonals'? If that correct, there a post with some answers about this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313308/get-all-the-diagonals-in-a-matrix-list-of-lists-in-python